# Arrow styles in TikZ trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Here's the LaTeX for a figure I'm working on:

```
\documentclass[sigplan,10pt,anonymous,review]{acmart}\settopmatter{printfolios=true,printccs=false,printacmref=false}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  breakarrow/.style={->, dashed},
  varnode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=red!20, bottom color=white}
}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node {/}
        child { node {tmp/}}
        child { node {initrd.img}}
        child { node {usr/}
          child { node {local/}}
          child { node {lib/}}
          child { node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$}
        child { node {share/} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
        child { node {bin/}
          child { node {cat}}
          child { node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
          child { node {tac}}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
      %% \caption{A directory tree with a deleted file}
      %% \label{directory-tree-1}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$}
        child { node {col} edge from parent [breakarrow]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A filesystem instrumented with body addresses.}
    \label{fig:body-addresses-col}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This is how it renders:

[image: example]

I would like to apply my `breakarrow` style to the edge between my node labelled `bin/` and its parent. However, if I just write `edge from parent [breakarrow]` after `node {bin/}`, I get unwanted behaviour - the same style starts applying to the parent edges for nodes `cat` and `tac` as well as node borders.

Could someone please help me find a way to apply my style to only the arrow between `bin/` and its parent?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @epR8GaYuh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are easier ways to draw trees, but if you wish to stick to TikZ's verbosity, you can override the style with another.

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  breakarrow/.style={->, dashed},
  myarrow/.style={solid, -},
  varnode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=red!20, bottom color=white}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em, every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
  \node {/}
  child { node {tmp/}}
  child { node {initrd.img}}
  child { node {usr/}
    child { node {local/}}
    child { node {lib/}}
    child { node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em, every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
  \node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$}
  child { node {share/} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
  child { node {bin/}  edge from parent [breakarrow]
    child { node {cat} edge from parent [myarrow]}
    child { node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
    child { node {tac} edge from parent [myarrow]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em, every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
  \node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$}
  child { node {col} edge from parent [breakarrow]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: override one style with another]

I would instead do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
  break arrow/.style={edge+={->, dashed}},
  my base node/.style={rounded corners, draw, align=center,},
  var node/.style = {my base node, top color=red!20, bottom color=white},
  my node/.style={my base node, top color=white, bottom color=violet!20,},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={my node, s sep'=3em, l sep'+=1em, }
  [$\alpha_{/usr}$, var node
    [share/]
    [bin/, break arrow
      [cat]
      [$\beta_{/usr/bin}$, var node, break arrow]
      [tac]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest solution]

Then you don't have to override anything and can apply styles precisely to the edges and nodes you want.

Answer (score 1):

[cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511668/173305) has a handy pointer to forest and does a good job bringing up simpler alternatives to TikZ, but I noticed that his TikZ-based answer caused certain cell borders to become dashed lines. Eventually I ended up figuring out how to get the nodes and edges to display correctly in TikZ.

```
\documentclass[sigplan,10pt,anonymous,review]{acmart}\settopmatter{printfolios=true,printccs=false,printacmref=false}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  breakarrow/.style={->, dashed},
  varnode/.style = {solid, shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=red!20, bottom color=white}
}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node {/}
        child { node {tmp/}}
        child { node {initrd.img}}
        child { node {usr/}
          child { node {local/}}
          child { node {lib/}}
          child { node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
      %% \caption{A directory tree with a deleted file}
      %% \label{directory-tree-1}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node [varnode] {$\alpha_{/usr}$}
        child { node {share/} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
        child { node {bin/} edge from parent [breakarrow]
          child { node [solid] {cat} edge from parent [solid,-]}
          child { node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$} edge from parent [breakarrow]}
          child { node [solid] {tac} edge from parent [solid,-]}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
      %% \caption{A directory tree with a deleted file}
      %% \label{directory-tree-1}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,
          every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=violet!20}]
        \node [varnode] {$\beta_{/usr/bin}$}
        child { node {col} edge from parent [breakarrow]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A filesystem instrumented with body addresses.}
    \label{fig:body-addresses-col}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```